# How can I update my edited XML file from a newer version of the same file?

Tags: xml

I tried to add the elements from the new XML to the old XML with a comparing tool, but the client won't run it and it will show as a corrupted file, not sure why.

I need to keep some elements from the old XML while adding the newly added elements from the update. I hope I'm explaining this well.

Is there any tool to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out [3DM](http://tdm.berlios.de/3dm/doc/index.html).  It can do XML aware 3-way merging.